# Would a black hole be slowed down as it passed through a large solid object?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, projectile

Say I get careless and drop a black hole. It falls through the Earth, passes through the core, and comes out on the other side.

Idealised as point masses, the black hole would reach an equal height on the other side of the Earth, and if I phone up a friend on the other side perhaps they could catch it. But if the mass of the Earth retards its motion the black hole would lose energy and not gain enough height on the other side, so it would "bounce" a number of times and end up in the core for as long as the core continues to exist.

- If the black hole were an ordinary ballistic object it would encounter resistance.
- But on the other hand the black hole is really just a region of space that everything falls into and since spacetime gets stretched I intuitively expect there to be more "room" for everything as it falls in (spaghettification) so there is no impact.
- But on the *other* other hand this would cause ripples in the rest of the planet so I suppose that energy has to come from somewhere.

That third point leads me to conclude that the black hole would lose energy and fail to reach an equal height on the other side, but because of the second point I don't see a mechanism for this energy loss.

So what actually happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black hole would be slowed by [dynamical friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_friction). The black hole pulls material toward itself, but as it continues to move, that material ends up behind it. This makes an excess of material behind the black hole, and the gravitational pull of that excess mass slows the black hole.

A secondary effect would be that as the black hole accretes material, it would pick up momentum from that material, also slowing it.