# Calculating dynamical friction of a black hole passing through solid matter

Tags: gravity, black-holes

Following up [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/806400) I am trying to calculate the [dynamical friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_friction) of a black hole passing through solid matter

> $$\frac{d\mathbf{v}_M}{dt} = -16 \pi^2 (\ln \Lambda) G^2 m (M+m) \frac{1}{v_M^3}\int_0^{v_M}v^2 f(v)  d v \mathbf{v}_M$$
>
> - G is the gravitational constant
> - M is the mass under consideration
> - m is the mass of each star in the star distribution
> - $v_M$  is the velocity of the object under consideration, in a frame where the
>   center of gravity of the matter field is initially at rest
> - ln(Λ) is the "Coulomb logarithm"
>   f(v) is the number density distribution of the stars

> A commonly used special case is where there is a uniform density in the field of matter, with matter particles significantly lighter than the major particle under consideration i.e., M ≫ and with a Maxwellian distribution for the velocity of matter particles i.e.,
>
> $$f(v) = \frac{N}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{v^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
>
> where N is the total number of stars and σ is the dispersion. In this case, the dynamical friction formula is as follows
>
> $$\frac{d\mathbf{v}_M}{dt} = -\frac{4\pi \ln (\Lambda) G^2  \rho M}{v_M^3}\left[\mathrm{erf}(X)-\frac{2X}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-X^2}\right]\mathbf{v}_M$$
>
> where
>
> - $X=v_M/(\sqrt{2}\sigma)$ is the ratio of the velocity of the object under consideration to the modal velocity of the Maxwellian distribution
> - ρ = m N  is the density of the matter field.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, for solid matter $\sigma$ tends to zero, so $X$ tends to infinity. It seems to imply that the drag increases without bound as the matter being struck freezes. I don't see how that can be right.

So how should I apply this equation to a black hole passing though, say, Earth?

Comment: This is a good question. The quoted formulas won't work since they assume matter consisting of free particles that can be flung around to transfer momentum. You would need corrections for a more rigid (or at least more viscous) medium.

Comment: Here are a couple videos from Scott Manley that should be a good resource. [Destroying The Earth With A Microscopic Black Hole - Let's Simulate It!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA-zkrCums0) and [Smashing An Asteroid All The Way Through Planet Earth!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=simuXjzxlGI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag given by those expressions doesn't increase without bound. Note that $\lim_{X\to\infty}\left[\mathrm{erf}(X)-\frac{2X}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-X^2}\right]=1.$ Alternatively, we could restore the three-dimensional integral in the first expression,
$$\frac{d\mathbf{v}_M}{dt} = -4 \pi (\ln \Lambda) G^2 m (M+m) \frac{\mathbf{v}_M}{v_M^3}\int_{|\mathbf{v}|<|\mathbf{v}_M|} f(\mathbf{v})d^3 \mathbf{v} ,$$
and substitute the distribution function $f(\mathbf{v})=(\rho/m)\,\delta^3(\mathbf{v})$ corresponding to a distribution of particles of mass $m$ with mass density $\rho$ and zero velocity ($\delta^3$ is the three-dimensional [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)). Either way, the result in the $m\ll M$ limit is
$$\frac{d\mathbf{v}_M}{dt} = -\frac{4\pi \ln (\Lambda) G^2  \rho M}{v_M^3}\mathbf{v}_M.$$

Note that this formula assumes that the matter is completely collisionless, and particles simply drift freely after the gravity of the black hole sets them in motion. There are corrections that could be made to account for the elasticity of solid material.

Comment: Wouldn’t a solid medium lead to a lot more than just corrections?

Comment: Intuitively I would think only if the black hole is subsonic, but it would be interesting to calculate.

Comment: @TimRias Seems my intuition is wrong, at least for gas. [Ostriker (1999)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9810324) noted that gaseous dynamical friction is more efficient for supersonic motion and less efficient for subsonic, compared to collisionless (Chandresekhar).